# Creating Alert Policy in Cloud Monitoring with OpenCensus Metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'd like to use an [OpenCensus metric](https://opencensus.io/exporters/supported-exporters/java/stackdriver-stats/) in a Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver) Alert Policy.

When I try to click the `Add` button, I get `This query must contain a resource type.` error. The odd thing, is that I *can* view this metric in MQL and can chart it.

According to the MQL charts that us this metric, the `Resource:` field is blank, and the charts work fine. The MQL charts show a resource type (on metric hover) of `knative_broker, dataflow_job, aws_rds_database, k8s_control_plane_component, aws_lambda_function, and 36 more`.

What `Resource` type should be used to alert on Open Census metrics in Cloud Monitoring alerts?

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Monitoring, application-specific metrics are typically called “custom metrics”. You can create custom metrics with opencensus. For more detailed information please follow [Custom Metrics with OpenCensus](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census). We define a Stackdriver exporter as the goal to create an alert policy on the aggregation of two metrics. Refer [Alert policy metric thresholds with stackdriver and opencensus](https://medium.com/kudos-engineering/alert-policy-metric-thresholds-with-stackdriver-and-opencensus-f9aab83b304a) for more information.